# Could not start mysql or MariaDB. Permissions were ok, but mysql-bin.index permission error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using MariaDB 5.5.36. Here's what I got while trying to start MariaDB:

```
# syslog
Dec 14 09:40:52 vps1497 mysqld_safe: Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Dec 14 09:40:52 vps1497 mysqld: 141214  9:40:52 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)
Dec 14 09:40:52 vps1497 mysqld: 141214  9:40:52 [ERROR] Aborting
Dec 14 09:40:52 vps1497 mysqld: 
Dec 14 09:40:52 vps1497 mysqld: 141214  9:40:52 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

# ls -alh /var/log/mysql/
-rw-rw----  1 mysql adm    9023947 Dec  8 03:01 mariadb-bin.002905
-rw-rw----  1 mysql adm       2550 Dec  7 03:01 mariadb-bin.index
```

Permissions seem fine, trying to start mysql with root doesn't work. Any clue?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `/var/log/mysql` fully owned by `mysql`

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Then go start MariaDB

Make sure you are logged in as abuser that can start MariaDB

If not, use sudo

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: `/var/log/mysql` and its contents are `mysql:adm`; `/var/lib/mysql` and its contents are `mysql:mysql`.

Answer (score 3):

If OS is Red Hat, it is possible that SELinux is stopping MariaDB from creating its log files.

Run `getenforce` as root. If output is *Enforcing* then run `setenforce 0`.

Output from `getenforce` should now be *Permissive*.

MariaDB should start now.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the error:

> mysqld: File '/var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index' not found (Errcode: 13)

Check 3 items:

1. Ensure the file exists.
2. Make sure the file is owner by mysql and the group is also set to mysql.
3. Set the permission on the file to "640"  (-rw-r-----).

This should resolve the problem for you.